# Emacs shell mode makes $PS1 different

Tags: bash, command-line, emacs, prompt

I have a custom $PS1 variable that looks like this on my command line: [image]

And on emacs using `M-x shell` unfortunately looks like this: [image]

Here is my $PS1 variable `export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\e[0;36m\]\T \[\e[1;30m\]\[\e[0;34m\]\u@\H\[\e[1;30m\] \[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[1;37m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\] \$ '`

How can I make emacs shell-mode look the same with my CLI variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the *set title* part to the terminals that support it:

```
case $TERM in
  (xterm*) set_title='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]';;
  (*) set_title=
esac
PS1=$set_title'\[\e[0;36m\]\T \[\e[1;30m\]\[\e[0;34m\]\u@\H\[\e[1;30m\] \[\e[0;32m\]\[\e[1;37m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\] \$ '
```

Comment: Your answer worked fine but when I go to shell mode everytime I use a command the previous name information and time are lost.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but in your prompt, you set the text colour to white, which may explain why you can't see things.

Comment: Ok fixed just changed the colours. It was that the ubuntu CLI background is purple and my output was white. But on emacs the background was already white so I couldn't see a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have some commands in your `PS1` that set the title of the terminal window. These are confusing the `emacs` shell. Changing your `PS1` to this should work:

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]\T \[\e[0;34m\]\u@\H \[\e[1;37m\]\w\[\e[0;37m\] \$ '
```

Comment: The  `\e]0;....\a` part sets the Window and icon title in `xterm`-like terminals.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas yes, I just understood that from your answer, thanks.